# Gatsby i18n: How to avoid creating pages for all locales?

Tags: gatsby, react-i18next, polylang

I use `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next` and `WP Polylang`  for multilanguage site with headless WordPress + gatsby.

The logic is that for pages that haven't translate version in WP Admin I just redirect user to home.

I see that in build I have static files for all locales and all posts event that post haven't translate in WP admin.

How I can skip build static files for some posts that haven't translates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your only option is to add them manually in the `gatsby-plugin-react-i18next` or include them into a regular expression using `matchPath` and `excludeLanguages`:

```
   pages: [
        {
          matchPath: '/:lang?/blog/:uid',
          getLanguageFromPath: true,
          excludeLanguages: ['es']
        },
      ]
```

*Note: you can add several instances in the array of `pages`.*